# EclipseLink - ConcurrencyException - signalAttemptedBeforeWait

Tags: java, tomcat, transactions, eclipselink

We've been working on an application that uses Tomcat 8 throught connection pool. We control Optimistic exceptions with @Version field, and we control transactions with Entitymanagers isolated by ThreadLocal.

However, the application triggers a concurrency exception sometimes with hangs other processes and requieres to restart the server.

The exception is always like this:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-2004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConcurrencyException
Exception Description: A signal was attempted before wait() on ConcurrencyManager. This normally means that an attempt was made to commit or rollback a transaction before it was started, or to rollback a transaction twice.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConcurrencyException.signalAttemptedBeforeWait(ConcurrencyException.java:84)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConcurrencyManager.releaseReadLock(ConcurrencyManager.java:468)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.CacheKey.releaseReadLock(CacheKey.java:475)
```

We've been trying to solve this problem or find any specific information about this error with no result. We even followed instructions in https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_diagnose_and_resolve_hangs_and_deadlocks.3F.

Disabling cache seems to solve the problem, but we cannt afford to not use cache due to performance needs.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Show more of the stack, as what you are calling that triggers it is important. You will also want to make sure that you aren't using single threaded resources (the EM and entities read from it) in different threads

Comment: Hi @Chris thanks for your answer. I realised that I had some non fetch="LAZY" OneToMany collections. Adding that option solved part of the problem. The second thing I realised is that quering from the JSP files using expresion language also can throw ConcurrencyException's, so I started moving querys to the java controller classes. It seemed to solve 99% of cases. But I still have got errors from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after six months of headaches, I managed to solve the problem.

The general error was **EclipseLink-2004**. If you check Eclipselink error reference:
[Eclipse link error reference page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink_Exception_Error_Reference_(ELUG)#Concurrency_Exceptions_.282001_.E2.80.93_2009.29), it says "Verify transactions in the application".

I've been using a application managed Entity Managers. To control that transactions were single-thread I used this ManagerHelper class:

[EntityManagerHelper](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/sandbox/trunk/jpa-mailreader/src/main/java/entity/EntityManagerHelper.java)

The problem was that I was putting a managed object inside a **Session** attribute. I don't really understand the process inside, but somehow it created new transactions outside the main transaction if it was used to query. Moving the object to **Request** attributes solved the problem.

I hope this helps to someone in the future.

Best regards